# How to check IF condition inside a class using $this->prefs['template'] in PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to check a if condition inside the   ($this->prefs['template'] = ''). I want to display a content with different color like {content } == 1 then data show in green color OR content != 1 data show in red color. I need a solution in this line -

```
<div class="content <?php if({content}=="1") { echo content_red;} else {echo "content_green";} ?>">{content}</div>
```

Based on the content from database.

Model.php:-

```php
public function __construct()
    {
        //parent::Model();
        $this->prefs = array(
        'start_day'    => 'monday',
        'month_type'   => 'long',
        'day_type'     => 'short',
        'show_next_prev' => TRUE,
        'next_prev_url'   => base_url().'/mycal/index/'
        );
        $this->prefs['template'] = '
        {table_open}
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calender">{/table_open}

        {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

        {heading_previous_cell}<th></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
        {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}" style="text-align:center;">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
        {heading_next_cell}<th></th>{/heading_next_cell}

        {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

        {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
        {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
        {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

        {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
        {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}
        {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
        {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}

        {cal_cell_content}
            <div class="day_num content_highlight">{day}</div>
            <div class="content <?php if({content}=="1") { echo content_highlight;} else {echo "";} ?>">{content}</div>
        {/cal_cell_content}
        {cal_cell_content_today}
        <div class="">
            <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
            <div class="content">{content}</div>
        </div>
        {/cal_cell_content_today}

        {cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
        {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

        {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

        {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}

        {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
        {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
        {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
        {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

        {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';
    }
public function add_calendar_data($data , $date)
    {
        $this->db->insert('calendar',array(
            'date'  => $date,
            'content'   => $data,
        ));
    }
```

Kindly give me a solution to fix it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? As this is a pure string, it should be treated as such

Comment: I have mention the error in exact line above. That if condition is show syntax error

Comment: You haven't mentioned any syntax error so far. Please do that by editing the question, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. As `$this->prefs['template']` contains a raw string, this is basic PHP string concatenation

Comment: You simply can't have PHP statements inside a string. You should it as a placeholder: `class="content {content_class}"`. Then you put the if-condition in PHP before you render the view, populating the variable `$content_class` with the correct value and pass it to the template.

Answer (score 0):

$this->prefs['template'] is string
use short if inside it

1. you must remove  from string
2. change your code from

   <div class="content <?php if({content}=="1") { echo content_highlight;} else {echo "";} ?>">{content}</div>

to

```
 <div class="content '.($content == "1" ? content_highlight : "").'">{content}</div>
```